# Docker compose exiting with status 1,spring boot starts in logs and ends immediately but cant identify cause of failure

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, javac

I am trying to have 11 docker compose running which depend on each other running.
2 of the 10 exit immediately after being created.
They are setup using a docker-compose.xml file with the -q flag
Docker logs  shows the below error.

```
Installing <xx>.crt in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
WARNING: ca-certificates.crt does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL: skipping
JVM Arguments: -Xms64m -Xmx512m -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dlogs_dir=logs/<container-name> -Dlogging.config=/app/logback-spring.xml  -Dspring.config.location=/app/config/override.yaml  -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
```

/usr/local/share/ca-certificates# does not have any certificate in the directory

is this something to do with editing the project's override file?
Cant ascertain where to diagnose
Entry in docker-compose file is like this(sensitive info removed)

```
image: ${NEXUS_DOCKER_REPO_NAME}-IMAGE PATH-latest
ports:
  - "8080:8080"
volumes:
  - <path to>/ca-certificates
  - <path to>/config
environment:
  - APP=<app name>
  - JVM_ARGS=-Xms64m -Xmx512m
  - DB_HOST=mariadb
  - DB_PORT=(port num)
  - DB_USERNAME=user
  - DB_PASSWORD=Userpass
  - DB_ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
  - DB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=adminpass
hostname:
  <hostname>
depends_on:
<dependencies>
logging:
  driver: "json-file"
  options:
    max-size: "30m"
    max-file: "5"
command:
  - /app/wait-for.sh
  - -q
  - -t
  - "300"
  - host:port
  - --
  - "/app/start-app.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the certificate file may have more than one certificate.

Try removing the unnecessary ones.

Answer (score 0):

yes ..it was an auth failure in one of the other containers which this was dependent on..more like a chained failure